# CSS: <table border="border"> equivalent

Tags: html, css

I have two different tables and on the second table I want to apply the border="border" atttribute as CSS. How can accomplish this correctly?

```
    <table>
        <!-- Text widgets for the customer's name and address -->
        <tr>
          <td>Buyer's Name:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="30" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Street Address:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="street" size="30" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>City, State, Zip:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="city" size="30" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="tableProduct">
        <!-- First, the column headings -->
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>

        <!-- Now, the table data entries -->
        <tr>
          <td>Unpopped Popcorn (1 lb.)</td>
          <td>$3.00</td>
          <td class="tdcenter">
            <input type="text" name="unpop" size="3" />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Caramel Popcorn (2 lb. canister)</td>
          <td>$3.50</td>
          <td class="tdcenter">
            <input type="text" name="caramel" size="3" />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Caramel Nut Popcorn (2 lb. canister)</td>
          <td>$4.50</td>
          <td class="tdcenter">
            <input type="text" name="caramelnut" size="3" />
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
```

I tried creating the classs tableProduct with the following:

```
.tableProduct {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

But it just creates a border around the table. I want it to create a border within each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go ... you weren't that far from it

```css
.tableProduct {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableProduct th,                 /*  this line is for the headers  */
.tableProduct td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <!-- Text widgets for the customer's name and address -->
  <tr>
    <td>Buyer's Name:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="name" size="30" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Street Address:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="street" size="30" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City, State, Zip:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="city" size="30" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="tableProduct">
  <!-- First, the column headings -->
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>

  <!-- Now, the table data entries -->
  <tr>
    <td>Unpopped Popcorn (1 lb.)</td>
    <td>$3.00</td>
    <td class="tdcenter">
      <input type="text" name="unpop" size="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Caramel Popcorn (2 lb. canister)</td>
    <td>$3.50</td>
    <td class="tdcenter">
      <input type="text" name="caramel" size="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Caramel Nut Popcorn (2 lb. canister)</td>
    <td>$4.50</td>
    <td class="tdcenter">
      <input type="text" name="caramelnut" size="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Wasn't sure how to combine the selectors for a class. I edited the css to look more like the original `.tableProduct {
    border-collapse: seperate;
 border: 1px solid black;
}`

Comment: @Rick That doesn't give you a border around each cell though, or you were mainly asking this question for "how-to" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
table.tableProduct td {
  border: 1px black solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

That will put a border around all of your table datas individually.

For good measure, you might want to add border-collapse in there. That way you're looking at one solid border, instead of two competing border lines - one from the table and one from the table data.

Edit: With css Combinators! By putting a space between `table.tableProduct` and `td`, we're saying, please apply these CSS rules to all `td` elements that a descendants of a `table` element with the class `tableProduct`.

Comment: How can I accomplish this so that it only applies to cells in the second table and not on all the cells on all the tables on the page?

Comment: @Rick with combinators! we can make some complex css selectors here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the styling to the `th` and `td` elements as well.

```
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can read up on table styling more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp).

Comment: Doing so applies to all tables, I just want the second table to apply the style.

Comment: @Rick just update the css selectors to `.tableProduct table, .tableProduct th, .tableProduct td`

Comment: It sounds like you are new to CSS. It might be a good idea to read up on selectors. http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/